# f(123) = 1! + 2! + 3! .I wrote a code for this type of function to work, have a look at it. My code is not giving desired result

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=123,c,h=0,fact=1,sum=0;

    for(int i=1;a>10;i++)
    {
        a/=pow(10,i);
        h++;
    }
    for(h;h>=0;h--)
    {
        c=a/pow(10,h);
        for(int j=1;j<=c;j++)
        {
            fact*=j;
        }
        sum+=fact;
        a-=(c*pow(10,h));
    }
    cout<<sum;
}
```

While using debugger I noticed that the line

`c=a/pow(10,h);`

is not working.

Here I have assigned `a=123`, but I want take it as input from the user. The variable `a` can be of any number of digits.

Can anyone suggest some other logic other than the one used in this code.

Comment: What's the expected result and why? Using `pow` and thus floating point arithmetic is likely to causes rounding errors that get truncated when you assign the result to a variable of type `int`.

Comment: Move `int fact=1;` down before inner loop at line 16. Otherwise you will get 1! * 2! * 3!.

Comment: `a/=pow(10,i);` is wrong. Each iteration of the loop should be dividing by 10; *period*. not by 10 raised to some number. You get the latter implicitly with each iteration. Also, when entering the second loop, what value of `a` do you think is being used when you do `c=a/pow(10,h);` ? Remember what your prior loop just finished doing to `a` ? Yeah, that's gone now. A *debugger*, looking at `a` would show you that, btw.

Comment: Two insights will make this exercise trivial: 1. learn to write unitary functions you can easily test; 2. unless you **actually** need **extreme** performance, manipulating the base-10 representation of a number is better done with strings.

Comment: 1. you need a function `f` that does what the exercise is about and don't bother read/write from/to standard in/output. You need a function taking a number and outputing a collection of its digit in base-10. You need a factorial function. Then you can write something as easy as `int f(int input) { auto const digits = base10digits(input) ; return std::accumulate(begin(digits), end(digits), 0, factorial); }`. See [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: 2. See [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and consorts.

Comment: How you got that 12? Do it first on paper before you start to program. Like that:  1! + 2! + 3! = 1 + 1*2 +1*2*3 = 1 + 2 + 6 = 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

// Factorial function:
// we just get: n * (n-1) * (n-2) ... * 1
// return type is long double because number may be big
// if we use it not only for one digit
long double get_factorial(int n){
    if (n == 1) 
        return 1; // for 1 factorial is 1
    else 
        return n * get_factorial(n - 1);
}

long double fact_sum(int a){
    long double sum = 0;  // variable for result
    while (a > 0) {       // while we have digits
       int fact = a % 10; // get last digit    
       a /= 10;           // then drop it   
       sum += get_factorial(fact); // accumulate result         
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    cout << fact_sum(123);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately your code is somehow not very understandable.

So, I will propose to use a common approach to solve that problem. One of your first problems is, how to get the digits from a number.

That can typically be solved with a standard approach: With modulo and integer division.

First we perform a modulo devision by 10. The result (the remainder) is the right hand digit of the input number.

With the example `456 % 10` we will get a 6 after the first modulo division. Then, in order to get the next digit, we do an integer division by 10. Result will be `456 / 10 = 45`. Then, we take again the 45 and perform the next modulo division. We get a 5. We continue to do this in a loop until the original number is 0.

So, something like

```
while (number > 0) {
    digit = number % 10;
    number /= 10;

    . . .
}
```

You will find such a solution very often.

Then, we calculate the factorial for each digit with a simple for loop. Of course, also a recursive function would be very easy to implement.

The factorial will be added to a global sum.

All this can then look like the below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Inform user, what to do
    std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter an unsigned integer number: ";

    // Read an integer number from the user and check, if that did work
    // So, do nothing, if user enters "abc"
    if (unsigned int integerNumber{}; std::cin >> integerNumber) {

        // Here we will store the resulting sum
        unsigned int resultingSum{};

        // Special case for integer number 0
        if (integerNumber == 0) ++integerNumber;

        // Get all digits from the given integer number
        while (integerNumber > 0) {

            // So, get next digit. Will get digits from right to left (but does not matter)
            unsigned int digit = integerNumber % 10;

            // Prepare for reading the next digit
            integerNumber /= 10;

            // Calculate the factorial of the digit. Can be max 9! = 362880
            unsigned int factorial{ 1 };
            for (unsigned int f{ 1 }; f <= digit; ++f)
                factorial = factorial * f;

            // Add the factorial for this digit to the sum
            resultingSum += factorial;
        }
        // Show result to the user
        std::cout << "\n\nSum of factorials of digits: " << resultingSum << "\n\n";

    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Problem with input\n\n";
}
```

Please note: The maximum factorial for one digit would be 9! = 362880. This will fit into an unsigned integer value. And even if we process an 11 digit input number, the resulting sum will also fit in an unsigned integer.

I assume 32bit for unsigned integer.

---

For such a small amount of numbers, like 10 digits only, you can also precalculate the factorial for the first 10 digits and use

```
const unsigned int factorial[10] = { 1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 70320, 362880 };
```

So, we initialize an constant array with compile time constants. If you do not want to calculate these values manually, you can also introduce a `constexpr` recursive function, to calculate compile time factorial values for you. Like so:

```
constexpr unsigned int F(unsigned int n) { return n == 0 ? 1 : n * F(n - 1); }
```

---

In whatever way you initialize the array, the factorial for a digit can then be calculated with:

```
unsigned int fact = factorial[digit];
```

That is of course ultrafast and maybe for this use case the recommended approach.

---

And, last but not least, you can work with strings.

One of the many possible implementations is below.

Please note:

- We use the above mentioned `constexpr` recursive function to calculate compile time factorial values.
- We associate a digit-character with a factorial via a `std::unordered_map`
- We also include leading '0' digits in the resulting sum. If you do not want to have this, then we can add easily a special handling

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <unordered_map>

// Compile Time calculation of a factorial
constexpr unsigned int F(unsigned int n) { return n == 0 ? 1 : n * F(n - 1); }

// Mapping digit-characters to factorials. Initial Values are compile Time values
std::unordered_map<char, const unsigned int> factorial{ {'0',F(0u)} ,{'1', F(1u)}, {'2', F(2u)}, {'3', F(3u)}, 
    {'4', F(4u)}, {'5',F(5u)}, {'6',F(6u)}, {'7',F(7u)}, {'8',F(8u)}, {'9',F(9u)} };

int main() {

    // Inform user, what to do
    std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter an unsigned integer number: ";

    // Read a number from the user
    if (std::string inputNumber{}; std::getline(std::cin, inputNumber)) {

        // Sanity check. Only digits are allowed
        if (std::all_of(inputNumber.begin(), inputNumber.end(), std::isdigit)) {

            unsigned long long sum{};

            // Sum up the factorials
            for (const char c : inputNumber) 
                sum += (factorial[c]);

            // Show result to the user
            std::cout << "\n\nSum of factorials of digits: " << sum << "\n\n";
        }
        else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Not a number\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Problem with input\n\n";
}
```

If you should have any questions, I am happy to answer.